# Will queries fall into a queue for run in the same order that they were requested (in mysqli Persistent Connection)?

Tags: mysqli

If hundreds of queries via mysqli(php extention) Persistent Connection be sent on the mysql at the same time, queries fall into a queue for run in the same order that they were requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will queries fall into a queue for run in the same order that they were requested?

Yes.
It doesn't matter if it's mysqli or persistent though.

It won't be "the same time" too.
Each persistent connection is used by only one PHP process at a time. And such a process being executed sequentially, running one query after another.

Comment: What's your mean from a PHP process ? A PHP process belong to what?